# Proof of the inequality $x^p - x^{p+1} \leq \frac{1}{p+1}$ for $p \in [0,1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $x \in [0,1]$. How can I show the inequality $x^p - x^{p+1} \leq \frac{1}{p+1}$?

Comment: This should be so simple you would already have some thoughts in your head when you penned this question down.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** We have by the Weighted AM-GM Inequality that $$x^p(p-px)\leq \left(\frac{px+(p-px)}{p+1}\right)^{p+1}\leq \frac{p}{p+1}\,.$$
(Here, $p$ can be any positive real number.)